# Unable to Migrate on .Net-Core 2.0 Add an Implementation of IDesignTimeDbContextFactory

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-2.0, duck-typing

**NOTE** This is not a duplicate, I am looking for an implementation that does not rely on Duck-Typing

I recently upgraded to .Net Core 2.0.  I tried to run migrations on my DB which failed with an error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'PersistedGrantDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory'

I did some research on the issue and found that I needed to modify my program.cs
The old code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Needs to transform to:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

//WTF? you have to name it this so migrations work
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => 
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
```

At first I figured that when you CreateDefaultBuilder it does some crafty registration for IDesignTimeDbFactory, but what is really weird is that, it only works when the method is named BuildWebHost.

Why is the new migrations based on such an abstract feature as Duck-Typing?

I'd prefer not to be tied into such an arbitrary thing, Can anyone show me how to run migrations without naming the method BuildWebHost?

Comment: This is just how asp.net core team decided things to work. They rely on that exact name.

Comment: That is there preferred method, but it's rare that Microsoft would rely on an implementation detail as the only way to configure things, are you 100% that is the only way to register?

Comment: I do not know an alternative.